# Syncing campaign members to data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a Salesforce campaign with 8000 records. My Marketing cloud connector is in place, but I can only see 1100 records in my designated data extension. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you tell me how your connector is configured? Scope by User or Non-Scope by User? [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_account_configuration_for_user_data_access.htm&type=5)

Comment: Hi @JeremyGarcia I had te reconfigure the connector. This way it worked!